# Renaming a file on FTP server with a timestamp variable

Tags: rename, date, ftp

From my linux machine, I connect remotely to an FTP server using the following command:

```
ftp ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@FTPSERVER/array1/DIR1/DIR2/
```

In this `DIR2` there is a file called `running_config` which is routinely deposited there,automatically, once a day.

I would like to append the value of date into the name of this file.
How can I can achieve this?

Comment: How exactly do you need this to happen? Why not use `cron` to take care of this? I'm pretty sure `logrotate` should be able to do this too. If not, you can always make a cron script that runs daily at a specific time, moves/copies your files and appends `$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` to its name.

Comment: I don't know how to write such complicated script.

Answer (score 1):

According to [man ftp](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/ftp.html):

> The `append` and `put` subcommands perform file-name expansion and
>   then use only the first file name generated. Other ftp subcommands,
>   such as `cd`, `delete`, `get`, `mkdir`, `rename`, and `rmdir`, do not
>   perform file-name expansion and take the pattern-matching characters
>   literally.

You could try something like:

```
ftp> put running_config running_config_021345
```

If you would like to append date, then you need to capture date as follows:

```
ftp> put running_config running_config_`date +%Y%m%d`.txt
```

Here is an example of a bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST_name='your_ftp_site'
USER='remote_user_name'
PW='remote_password'

ftp -n -v $HOST_name << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PW
prompt
 put running_config running_config_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.txt

EOT
```

Comment: how can I capture date as a variable and code the process in this case?